# How to generate ny video Thumnail?

Tags: reactjs

I m using ReactPlayer to play videos how can i get video thumbnails

```
<ReactPlayer
     url={'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LG5xccAHmN8'}
     className='livecx-player'
     width='100%'
     height='100%'
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use option "light"

```
<ReactPlayer
     url={'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LG5xccAHmN8'}
     className='livecx-player'
     width='100%'
     height='100%'
     light
/>
```